# r order data frame using apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame over which I want to preform the following operations:

1) Reodrer the data frame according to a ceratin column (containing numeric data).

2) Add a column to the data frame which assigns to each row a number based on the order of the column I used to order.

3) Reorder the data frame by the rownames: I need this since I want to apply steps 1-2 several times using a different column, and I don't want the order from the previous run to be retained between runs.

I wrote a function that does what I want:

```
 globalQ<-function(df,x){
 df<-df[order(df[,x]),]
 leng<-length(which(is.na(df[,x])==FALSE))
 lengu<-as.integer((leng)/6)
 qvec<-c(rep(1,lengu),rep(2,lengu),rep(3,leng-5*lengu),rep(4,lengu),rep(5,lengu),   rep(6,lengu),rep(NA, times=nrow(df)-leng))
 df$name<-qvec
 df
 }
```

This works well for one column at a time, say:
     df<-globalQ(exProbes,14).

But I want to do this using several different columns, calling the function on one column at a time.

I guess what I need is some version of apply(), but I'm at a loss as how to call apply() using a functuon of both the data frame and a single column.

BTW, I'm aware of the fact that calling this function on mutiply columns will create a names redundcny on the new columns it will create. I will handle that later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to sort the dataframe each time you call the function. You can return the result in such an order that you can `cbind` it to the original dataframe and order it later. Like this:

```
qvec<-function(y){
 leng<-sum(!is.na(y))
 lengu<-as.integer((leng)/6)
 qvec<-c(rep(1:2,each=lengu),rep(3,leng-5*lengu),rep(4:6,each=lengu),rep(NA,length(y)-leng))
 qvec[order(order(y))]
}

with(mtcars, cbind(mtcars, name1=qvec(cyl), name2=qvec(disp))[order(cyl, disp),])
```

To call this with an arbitrary vector of column indices (`indices`) and later order by row names, use something like this:

```
result <- mtcars
for(i in indices) result <- cbind(result, qvec(mtcars[,i]))
result[order(rownames(mtcars)),]
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a direction I did'nt think of

Answer (score 0):

```
## for example,1's,2's,4's column is what you need,exProbes is your matrix
indices<-c(1,2,4)
x<-globalQ(exProbes,indices[1])
if (length(indices)>1) {
    for (i in indices[-1]) {
        x<-data.frame(x,globalQ(exProbes,i)) 
    }
}
```